# Андроид, как описать лого в NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-navigation-drawer

Я хочу использовать [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer), похоже что пользоваться ей очень удобно, но я не понимаю как поместить свой логотип в верхнюю часть Drawer'a вместо картинки. дело в том, что сам логотип маленький и я хотел бы чтобы на месте картинки был фон определенного цвета и размера, а поверх, по центру накладывался логотип. Вроде как это можно сделать кодом, но я не понимаю как..
Буду очень благодарен за помощь

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
            .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.first_folder).withIcon(R.mipmap.ic_folder),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.second_folder).withIcon(R.mipmap.ic_folder),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.third_folder).withIcon(R.mipmap.ic_folder)
                                    )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    //заполнение списка файлами
                    if (position == 1)
                        parseFile(getFileNameFromAssets(getString(R.string.first_folder)));
                    else if (position == 2)
                        parseFile(getFileNameFromAssets(getString(R.string.second_folder)));
                    else if (position == 3)
                        parseFile(getFileNameFromAssets(getString(R.string.third_folder)));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + position + "; " + drawerItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();
                    return false;
                }
                })
                .build();
```

Также непонятно как добавить кнопку настроек, обычно она справа на тулбаре и выглядит как 3 точки
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Видимо вам нужно все это сделать в своей разметке `R.layout.drawer_header` - сделать контейнер-фон и поместить туда виджет, какой-нибудь `ImageView` со своим логотипом, спозиционировать его как вам надо. А то, что на скриншотах в кружочке, то эта иконка и фон устанавливаются через класс `AccountHeader` - используется для авторизации.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#add-profiles-and-an-accountheader) вроде метод `withHeaderBackground` на сколько понял для фона, но могу ошибаться